# Как получить CSRF ключ (токен)?

Tags: python, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup, csrf

Как получить CSRF токен с сайта https://fix-price.ru/personal/ для парсинга данных из личного кабинета?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import fake_useragent


HOST = 'https://fix-price.ru/'
link = 'https://fix-price.ru/ajax/auth_user.php'

HEADERS = {
    'accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
    'referer': 'https://fix-price.ru/personal/',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77 Safari/537.36',
    'x-kl-ajax-request': 'Ajax_Request'
}

# session = requests.Session()
# resp = session.get(link, headers=HEADERS)
# soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')
# csrf = soup.find('input', {'name': 'csrfToken'})

client = requests.Session()

html = client.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')
# soup = BeautifulSoup(client.get(link).text, "html.parser")
csrf = soup.find('input', {'name': 'csrfToken'})

data = {
    'AUTH_FORM': 'Y',
    'TYPE': 'AUTH',
    'backurl': '/personal/',
    'auth_method': 'phone',
    'login': '*****',
    'password': '*****',
    'CSRF': csrf
}

session = requests.Session()
user = fake_useragent.UserAgent().random

header = {
    'user-agent': user
}

response = session.post(link, data=data, headers=header).text
```

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 5):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обновите заголовок **сессии** requests, а `csrf` найдете в `value`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://fix-price.ru/personal/'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36'}

session = requests.Session()
session.headers.update(headers)

r = session.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

csrf = soup.find('input', {'name': 'CSRF'})['value']
```

теперь в `csrf` - строка с токеном:

```
>>> csrf
'de59e151cbbc004f009c32e6436c3e05fee6fb365778a5ed43ff5ccf9fd6f31b'
```

И потом, **используя эту же сессию**, отправите `post` для авторизации:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как-то так:

```
url_auth = 'https://fix-price.ru/ajax/auth_user.php'

phone = '+7 (123) 456-78-90'
password = 'qwerty'

payload = {
    'AUTH_FORM': 'Y',
    'TYPE': 'AUTH',
    'CSRF': csrf,
    'backurl': '/personal/',
    'auth_method': 'phone',
    'login': phone,
    'password': password
}

r = session.post(url_auth, data=payload)
```